# In Python, what is the faster way to calculate an EMA by reusing the previous calculations?

Tags: python, moving-average, ta-lib

I have been using TA-Lib to calculate EMAs but each time I add a new number to the array, TA-Lib performs the calculation from scratch again.

I am doing analysis on a rather large set of data (> 1M rows) and this is quite slow.

What would be the fastest way to calculate the new EMA when a new value is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `x` be the vector of length `n` containing your samples, that is `x[0]`, ..., `x[n-1]`. Let `y` be the vector containing the EMA. Then `y` is given by the equation:

```py
y[k] = y[k-1] * a + x[k] * (1-a)
```

Where `a` is the EMA parameter, which is between 0 and 1. The closer to 1, the smoother the curve.

Therefore, to compute the EMA you just need:

```py
a = 0.9
y[0] = x[0]
for k in range(1, n):
    y[k] = y[k-1]*a + x[k]*(1-a)
```

Then if you get another sample, that is `x[n]`, you can compute the EMA `y[n]` without doing the full calculation with:

```
y[n] = y[n-1]*a + x[n]*(1-a)
```

This is pseudocode, so if you use lists, it should be something like this:

```
y.append(y[-1]*a + x[-1]*(1-a))
```

**Edit:**

If you really want to improve speed for the computation of the EMA (the whole EMA at a time), you can use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) and numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from timeit import timeit

n=1000000
x_np = np.random.randn(n) # your data
x_list = list(x_np)
a = 0.9

def ema_list(x, a):
     y = [x[0]]
     for k in range(1, n):
          y.append(y[-1]*a + x[k]*(1-a))
     return y


@njit("float64[:](float64[:], float64)")
def ema_np(x, a):
     y = np.empty_like(x)
     y[0] = x[0]
     for k in range(1, n):
          y[k] = y[k-1]*a + x[k]*(1-a)
     return y


print(timeit(lambda: ema_list(x_list, a), number=1)) # 0.7080 seconds
print(timeit(lambda: ema_np(x_np, a), number=1)) # 0.008015 seconds
```

The list implementation takes about 708 ms whereas the numba and numpy takes 8 ms, that is about 88 times faster. The numpy implementation without numba takes similar time to the list implementation.

Comment: Maybe using ```map``` instead of the ```for``` loop could improve speed ?

Comment: I don't see how to use `map`, because the value of each element to be computed depends on the previous element. If you want speed, you can use `numba`, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Great, I was thinking of some way of applying concurrency  and avoid the ```for``` loop. But maybe the ```loop``` is inevitable for the calculation as you said.

Comment: `y[k] = y[k-1] + (1-a) * (x[k] - y[k-1])` may give better precision

Comment: when comparing timing with numba you are not supposed to run it for 1 iteration as the efficiency kicks in after the 5th or 6th iteration. The njit code will mostly take few microseconds depending on your processor

Answer (score 0):

There is a fork of `TA-Lib` named `TA-Lib RT` that can be used for data that coming in a real time without recalculation of whole dataset.

https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt

It contains additional variants of TA functions that are designed to work in a loops and process single data value per call instead of array. These functions accept `state` arguments to keep internal state between calls.

Unfortunately it lacks python bindings yet. I'm currently trying to make such binding by forking original TA-Lib python bindings.